# jQuery - Unable to submit dynamically created form

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble submitting a dynamically created form. I have tried a lot of methods but the form is not getting submitted. Here are couple of methods I have tried.

In this code `tosubmit` is actually a json string created using `JSON.stringify`. I am also not getting any error when I debug this using `Opera Dragonfly`. I can see the form properly added to the DOM.

**Method 1**

```
var frmstr = '<form id="tbl_tmpfrm" method="post" action="/test.php">';
frmstr +='<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="data" value=""/></form>';
$('body').append(frmstr);
$('#tbl_tmpfrm').find('input[name="data"]').val(tosubmit);
$('#tbl_tmpfrm').submit();
```

**Method 2**

```
var frmstr = '<form id="tbl_tmpfrm" method="post" action="/test.php">';
frmstr +='<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+tosubmit+'"/></form>';
$('body').append(frmstr).submit();
```

I am able to successfully submit the `tosubmit` and validate at the server side when i use `ajax`. But I want a normal commit. What am I doing wrong?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the name `submit` for the hidden field, this can cause problems.

Comment: @roland any suggestions. I just want to submit 2 values, and not using `ajax`. I am open to any method.

Comment: Any other name will do. You just can't use submit() on a form if you have an input element with the name "submit".

Comment: @roland Thanks a lot. I must be too tired, don't know how i missed that. Please post this as an answer and I can accept it.

Comment: I couldn't find the issue with the original code so I created a jsfiddle to reproduce the error. You can see it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PtGQk/1/) with the solution provided by @roland.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the name `submit` for the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/>
```

You can't use submit() on a form if you have an input element with this name.

Answer (score 18):

For dynamically added elements use this form

```
$(document).on('submit','#tbl_tmpfrm',function(){})
```

EDIT:
This was not what was required exactly. 
Try adding the form as an object not string

```
var frmstr = $('<form id="tbl_tmpfrm" method="post" action="/test.php"></form>');
$(document).append(frmstr);
frmstr.append('<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="true"/><input type="hidden" name="data" value="'+tosubmit+'"/>');
frmstr.submit();
```

Also, as suggested by roland, dont use the name submit for the hidden field

Comment: This just adds an event handler to the form, but i want to just submit as if submit button is clicked in good old plain HTML form.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry for overlooking the problem. Try the edited answer

Answer (score 3):

you need to use 'on'; try this code here:

```
$("#tbl_tmpfrm").on("submit", function() { 

});
```

Comment: and removed as for jq 1.9