# jquery multiple dynamic forms on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

jQuery 1.11.0

http://jsfiddle.net/sfvyxunj/

```
$(".myForm").on("submit", function(event){ });
```

I can't get jQuery's .on to work on dynamically created forms.

I've tried several variations of the .on statement, but if the forms are loaded from ajax dynamically then it just doesn't want to work.

Note: The settimeout was used to simulate an ajax request. fiddle gives an error, but on a server the form would just reload the page and bypass jQuerys .on

Thanks in advance.

Comment: incorrect usage of `on()` for event delegation see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18014104/1175966

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sfvyxunj/1/ 

Thanks ! I knew it was something stupid gerr. I provided the updated fiddle incase someone wanted to see how to make it work.

Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

Comment: the important part to understand is that if the intial selector doesn't exist when code runs, you need to delegate to an element ( or the document) that does when you run the code

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to attach the .on to an element that already existed on the page when .on was called. Not sure how I missed it, but the code should look like this:

```
$("#container").on("submit", ".theForms", function (event) {   });
```

The corrected jsfiddle:

```
jsfiddle.net/sfvyxunj/1
```

Thanks to charlietfl for pointing out my mistake.